# solve $\big(f^{-1}\big)'(0)\qquad \mbox{with}\qquad f(x)=\int_1^x\cos^2(e^t)\,dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

How to solve
$$\big(f^{-1}\big)'(0)\qquad \mbox{with}\qquad f(x)=\int_1^x\cos^2(e^t)\,dt$$

I tired applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus but I couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the formula that $(f^{-1})'(0)=\dfrac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(0))}=\dfrac{1}{f'(1)}$ since $f(1)=\displaystyle\int_{1}^{1}\cos^{2}(e^{t})dt=0$.

$f'(x)=\cos^{2}(e^{x})$, so $f'(1)=\cos^{2}(e)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how $(f^{−1})′(0)=\frac{1}{f′(f^{−1}(0))}=\frac{1}{f′(1)}$ ? I understand the rest of the computations, but i can't understand this part

Comment: You can use Chain Rule to deduce from $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ that $(f^{-1})'(f(1))f'(1)=1$, so $(f^{-1})'(f(1))=1/f'(1)$.

Comment: Note that $f(1)=0$, don't get confused here, it is compatible.

Comment: but how does $\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(0))} = \frac{1}{f'(1)}$?

Comment: Because $f(1)=0$, so $f^{-1}(0)=1$.